# TypeScript defining key and value for Object probably with discrimination union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

I want to define what kind of value is permitted inside an object, based on a defined interface/type:

```
type StorageValuesSyncOptions = {
  toDoOrNotToDo: boolean,
  piecesOfEight: number,
  poem: string,
};

type SyncOptions<Options extends StorageValuesSyncOptions = StorageValuesSyncOptions> = {
  [key in keyof Options]: SyncOption<Options, Options[key]>;
};

type SyncOption<K, V> = {
  id: keyof K,
  value: V,
};
```

As long as I use `SyncOptions` I have a guarantee that 'SyncOption' is on the format specified in `StorageValuesSyncOptions`. However I want to flesh out the generics of SyncOption so that it will be locked in that way. I think I need to use a discriminated union, and a default value would be nice so I didn't need to specify the generics.

As an example this works as expected:

```
const options: SyncOptions = {
  toDoOrNotToDo: {
    id: 'toDoOrNotToDo',
    value: true, //3 will result in an error
  },
  piecesOfEight: {
    id: 'piecesOfEight',
    value: 7, //"string" will result in an error
  },
  poem: {
    id: 'poem',
    value: "You and me", // true will not work
  },
};
```

I would like this to result in an error:

```
  const poem: SyncOption = {
    id: 'poem',
    value: true //"but a string" should be valid
  },
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the point of the generic type parameters is since the example is mostly just using their defaults.  Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnAhgcwgNWQGwK4QGcYQA7AYwHkxgBLeEgqAXigG8BYAKCh6gQBF4FRADl4wACrxBALigAjePGwRkJADRdeUMDQhlCFAGYBRGqgAWwOSVwBbeRESbuvMPAh25BYIholUFwBfAG4uLlBIWFJKajoGZjYoAG0AaSh-KABrCBB4I1gEFHQsPEJicipaegIAXTlWDIATOVT1KAA3HHw5OCQ0TG7ymKr4gjTaqCCpsM5I6ArY6pJExdGa5Jy8grW4mtrwzi4gA) work for you? If not can you show a use case where the generics are not just using their defaults?

Comment: Yes that was certainly an easier way to achieve this.